# Get the extreme value with equation of line passing through point

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

[image]

I didn't have any idea about the question. First, I asked ChatboxGPT and got the hint, then wrote the below solution for (5-1).

\begin{array}{l}
\because q=Ap+B\Longrightarrow B=q-Ap\\
\therefore A^{2} +B^{2} =A^{2} +( q-Ap)^{2} =A^{2} +q^{2} -2Apq+A^{2} p^{2}\\
\frac{d}{dA}\left( A^{2} +B^{2}\right) =2A-2pq+2p^{2} A,\ \frac{d^{2}}{dA^{2}}\left( A^{2} +B^{2}\right) =2+2p^{2}  >0\\
\therefore let\ \frac{d}{dA}\left( A^{2} +B^{2}\right) =0\ would\ get\ the\ minimum\ of\ A\\
2A-2pq+2p^{2} A=0\\
2A\left( 1+p^{2}\right) =2pq\\
A_{min} =\frac{pq}{1+p^{2}}\\
\therefore B_{min} =q-A_{min} p=q-\frac{pq}{1+p^{2}} =\frac{q}{1+p^{2}}\\
\therefore A_{min}^{2} +B_{min}^{2} =\left(\frac{pq}{1+p^{2}}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{q}{1+p^{2}}\right)^{2} =\frac{p^{2} q^{2} +q^{2}}{\left( 1+p^{2}\right)^{2}}
\end{array}

I'm confused about getting the minimum value of $A^{2} +B^{2}$ through the minimum value of A. When A is minimum, B(y-intercept) is maximum. Is it correct to obtain the minimum value? If it is correct, what about through the minimum value of B to get the answer? (I'm sorry I don't have reference answer)

For (5-2), here is my idea.
\begin{array}{l}
\because |a+b|\leqslant |a|+|b|\\
\therefore ( |A|+|B|)_{min} =\sqrt{( A+B)^{2}} =\sqrt{A^{2} +B^{2} +2AB}
\end{array}
Please tell me if it is correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $A_{min}$ is not the minimum value of A, rather it is that value of A which minimises the value of $A^2+B^2$.

Comment: For (5-1) the minimum is $\frac{q^2}{p^2+1}$.

Comment: For (5-2) the minimum value is **$\min \left(\left| \frac{q}{p}\right| ,| q| \right)$**

Comment: I agree with insipidintegrator. Also, can you see that you can further simplify $A_{min}^2+B_{min}^2$ (see gpmath's comment)

Comment: @gpmath Thanks for your answer. For (5-2), I don't understand how to get the answer. Would it be possible for you to explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (5-2):

Let $G(A,B)\mapsto |A|+|B|$.

Then $G_{min}(A,p,q)= G(A,q-A p) = |A|+|q-A p|$.

HINT: The $|x|$ function has one global minimum at $x=0$.

Hence $G_{min}(A,p,q)$ may be minimal at $G_{min}(0,p,q)=|q|$ or $G_{min}(\frac{q}{p},p,q)=|\frac{q}{p}|$, whoever is smaller.

Finally we get the minimum value at $min(|\frac{q}{p}|,|q|)$.